# Increase numbers in python until max

Tags: python

I want to have python spit out a bunch of numbers for me.
example:

```
>>>date = 1940
>>>date += 1
>>>print str(date)
1941
>>>
```

but i want to loop that and output all numbers from 1940-2004

Comment: [This is all the effort I'm willing to put into this question](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Hey, you bothered to get a URL and put a link in your comment.  That's probably more than this question deserves already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function.

```
for i in range(1940,2005):
   print i
```

Comment: alternatively if you are memory constrained, use xrange and .next()

Comment: The answer above is the best answer unless you want to use a while loop instead